# Re-process all nagios data with pnp4nagios

Tags: nagios

I have moved to a new `nagios` installation (new server). I have transfered the data from the original server (`/var/log/nagios2/archives`) to my new server (`/var/log/nagios3/archives`) (I think they have compatible format). Now I would like to regenerate the pnp4nagios graphs using this historical data.

This is the command I have to process data on the fly:

```
/usr/lib/pnp4nagios/libexec/process_perfdata.pl --bulk=/var/lib/pnp4nagios/perfdata/host-perfdata
```

But this is just processing new data in `/var/lib/pnp4nagios/perfdata/host-perfdata`.

I have several questions:

- Where does pnp4nagios store the processed data (graphs)?
- How can I force pnp4nagios to regenerate all graphs?

Answer (score 1):

pnp4nagios will call process_perfdata.pl which itsself invokes a call to rrdtool, storing the graph data within round robin databases (rrds). Within your pnp4nagios configuration, you should find the logical path for those on disk, letting you backup/move that data.
I'm just guessing that you already have pnp4nagios 0.6 (of not, look for the 0.4 docs): 
http://docs.pnp4nagios.org/pnp-0.6/webfe_cfg (look for rrdbase)

But keep in mind - you cannot move rrds between different architectures. i.e. old server i386, new server amd64 - does not work at all by just copying stuff with rsync/scp. Look here for details: http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/doc/rrddump.en.html

Further, you should consider moving from the synchronous mode (which yours is) to "bulk mode with npcd and npcdmod" which will create asynchronous spooling, decreasing blocking the core when perfdata processing hangs (lower latency in case).

If you happen to have further questions on pnp4nagios itsself, you might like the idea of posting your questions to the monitoring-portal.org as well where the devs are reading too.

Answer (score 0):

The nagios.log (and log archives) do not contain the perfdata information.  What you need to do is move the .rrd & .xml files to the new server from the perfdata directory.

Nagios doesn't log or retain the perfdata, at runtime if processing of perfdata is enable it will process it and then cheal it's hands of it.